# How to construct the probability space for an infinite withdrawing ball process?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I recently encountered a fascinating probability problem and am keen to explore its well-defined nature. Imagine an infinitely-capacious bag where, at each time point $1-2^{-x}$, with $x$ being a non-negative integer, we place 10 balls into the bag. Subsequently, we draw a single ball from the bag, adhering to one of the following rules:

1: Randomly select the oldest ball in the bag to break any ties.

2: Randomly select the newest ball in the bag to break any ties.

The question at hand pertains to the probability of successfully drawing a ball from the bag at time 1, given these two rules. Surprisingly, the answer is 0 and 1. If we opt for the newest ball, there will always be previously placed balls remaining in the bag (10 - 1 > 0). On the other hand, if we choose the oldest ball, a ball inserted at time $1-2^{-x}$ will be drawn from the bag at time $1-2^{-y}$ for some $y \gg x$. So at time 1, the bag has no balls.

How can we construct the probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ for this game in order to precisely define the probability of drawing balls at time 1?

Comment: This needs some more context: you don't seem to have told us what the criteria for success are. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: To sucessfully draw a ball, we need to have balls inside the bag at time 1. I have try to use kolmogrov extension theorem, but it seems to be not applicable here.

Comment: Your description of the problem still doesn't make any sense to me. Can you provide a reference for the problem, please?

Comment: The original problem is stated in chinese. Which of the problem description make you confused?